# Deriving HList of zeroes from a type of HList of Monoids

Tags: scala, functional-programming, shapeless

I am learning shapeless, and currently I am trying to create a function that does the following: 
given a type of an `HList` it returns the `HList` of `None`s, with the `Option` types corresponding to given `HList` type.

For instance:

```
create[String :: Int :: HNil] // returns None[String] :: None[Int] :: HNil
```

So the logic is the following:

```
def create[A <: HList] {
 type HT = ??? //somehow getting Head type
 type TT = ??? //somehow getting Tail type
 // if HT is HNil  HNil else Option.empty[HT] :: create[TT] 
}
```

Looks like the `HT` and `TT` can be provided by`IsHCons`

```
def createHList[L <: HList](implicit ihc: IsHCons[L]): HList = {
    type HT = ihc.H
    type TT = ihc.T
    //
}
```

But that rises two problems

1. How to compare types?
2. Compiler can not find `IsHCons[TT]` for recursive call. (How to get `ISHCons[TT]` from `IsHCons[L]`? It is not even possible for `HNil`!)

I think that I can get around the (1), by providing implicits for `HNil` and non `HNil`, so the compiler will pick up the right implicit, depending on the type.

Am I moving towards the right direction?

Given that, may be it is worth to ask more general question. Given the `HList` of Monoids, is it possible to derive zero `HList`, consisting of zeros of give monoids?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's fairly easy to define `Monoid` instance for every `HList` where each element type has its `Monoid` instance:

```
trait Monoid[T] {
  def zero: T
  def plus(t1: T, t2: T): T
}

object Monoid {
  implicit val HNilMonoid: Monoid[HNil] = new Monoid[HNil] {
    def zero = HNil
    def plus(hn1: HNil, hn2: HNil) = HNil
  }
  implicit def HConsMonoid[H, T <: HList](implicit hm: Monoid[H], tm: Monoid[T]): Monoid[H :: T] = 
    new Monoid[H :: T] {
      def zero = hm.zero :: tm.zero
      def plus(ht1: H :: T, ht2: H :: T) = 
        hm.plus(ht1.head, ht2.head) :: tm.plus(ht1.tail, ht2.tail)
    }
}
```

(actually, I would expect shapeless to be able to derive the above automatically, but I'm not an expert on shapeless)

Now, assuming that we have `Monoid[Int]` and `Monoid[String]` defined elsewhere, you can just:

```
implicitly[Monoid[Int :: String :: HNil]].zero
```

which is exactly what you want, i.e. a `HList` of zeros.

Comment: There is also a similar [shapeless example](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/monoids.scala) deriving `Monoid`.