# Combine 2 vectors of a custom type to return 1 vector

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have a class:

```
case class Custom(label: String, num: Long)
```

Given these two lists:

```
val l1 = Vector(Custom("a", 1), Custom("aa", 1))
val l2 = Vector(Custom("a", 1))
```

I wish to obtain the resulting list:

```
val l3 = Vector(Custom("a", 2), Custom("aa", 1))
```

I've attempted using fold like so:

```
l1.foldLeft(l2)((acc: List[Custom], el: Custom) => {
   val itemWithIndex: Option[(Custom, Int)] = acc.zipWithIndex.find(_._1.label == el.label)
   itemWithIndex match {
     case Some(x) => acc.updated(x._2, Custom(el.label, acc(x._2).num + el.num))
     case None => el :: acc
   }
})
```

This implementation iterates the accumulator( `l2` ) 3 times, and the `l1` once. I'm looking for a more efficient solution.

Comment: Cool. And what have you tried?

Comment: A foldLeft where the accumulator starts as the second list. Then for each item in the first list, check if it exists, if it does, add the values, otherwise insert the value as a new element. It isn't very efficient. Iterating the entire list to check if something exists, and then also again to get its position.

Comment: Edit your question and explain your approach there; make your question self-contained.

Comment: updated the answer with a slow implementation

Comment: This is to fun not to solve on your own so I'll provide some help as to how I would approach it. Combine the two lists to form a new list, then group this combined list by `a`, and map each grouped item to a new `Custom` class using the first element and counting the size of the second. Hope the helps.

Comment: Thanks Brian, good idea combining the lists before hand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 import scalaz.syntax.monoid._
  case class Custom(label: String, num: Long)
  val l1 = Vector(Custom("a", 1), Custom("aa", 1))
  val l2 = Vector(Custom("a", 1))

  def toM(v: Vector[Custom]): Map[String, Long] = {
    (v map (cus ⇒ cus.label → cus.num)).toMap
  }

  def fromM(m: Map[String, Long]): Vector[Custom] = {
    m.map{case (l , num) ⇒ Custom(l, num)}.toVector
  }

  implicit val myMonoid = new Monoid[Vector[Custom]] {
    import scalaz.std.anyVal.longInstance
    val mm = scalaz.std.map.mapMonoid[String, Long]

    override def zero: Vector[Custom] = fromM(mm.zero)

    override def append(f1: Vector[Custom], f2: ⇒ Vector[Custom]): Vector[Custom] = fromM(mm.append(toM(f1), toM(f2)))
  }



  println(l1 |+| l2) \\Vector(Custom(a,2), Custom(aa,1))
```

If you want to be more clear, you can extract `toM` and `fromM` to Isomorphism instance.

Comment: Very clean, is there any way to apply this or a similar abstraction to a case class with > 2 parameters?

Comment: Sure, that it is achievable with shapeless. You can convert any case class to the `HList` and back, and that is not difficult to define `Monoid` for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363337/deriving-hlist-of-zeroes-from-a-type-of-hlist-of-monoids

Answer (score 2):

Brian gave a nice suggestion to simply combine the lists before hand like so:

```
(l1 ++ l2)
  .groupBy(_.label)
  .map { 
    case (label, customs) => Custom(label, customs.map(_.num).sum)
  }
```

The `groupBy` gives us a `Map[String, List[Custom]]` where `List[Custom]` is all the `Custom` objects that have the same label. All that's left is to sum up that `List`, and create a new `Custom` object with this sum for each label.

Since this is a reduction, it can be made into a Monoid:

```
implicit def customMonoid = new Monoid[Vector[Custom]] {
  override def append(l1: Vector[Custom], l2: => Vector[Custom]): Vector[Custom] =
    (l1 ++ l2)
      .groupBy(_.label)
      .map {
        case (a, b) => Custom(a, b.map(_.num).sum)
      }.toVector

  override def zero: Vector[Custom] = Vector.empty[Custom]
}
```

Comment: you can also define `def add(b: Custom): Custom = copy(num = num + b.num)` on `Custom` and then the body of your `case` statement above could be `customs reduce (_ add _)`

Comment: Very nice suggestion, I'll definitely be implementing it with that improvement.

Comment: Looking at it now, I think it is slightly more readable with the Custom object being created in the map. Since this function only operates on `Vector[Custom]`, I don't think I gain enough abstracting out Custom's add function to justify the slight readability hit.

Comment: i agree you should choose what is more readable. it's hard to tell from my end, i assume `Custom` is a made up type just for the purpose of this post? without knowing what the actual type is, i wouldn't be able to decide if an `add` method belongs on it.

Comment: Good point, this code example is made up. The real implementation is quite different. However this `mergeByField` like function does appear to be reusable if both the groupBy field and the add function get abstracted out.